# Wso2is username regex not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

This is my UserStoreManager inside my user-mgt.xml config file:

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager">
        <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager</Property>
        <Property name="ReadOnly">false</Property>
        <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="IsEmailUserName">true</Property>
        <Property name="DomainCalculation">default</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordDigest">SHA-256</Property>
        <Property name="StoreSaltedPassword">true</Property>
        <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
        <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameUniqueAcrossTenants">false</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">^[^~!#$;%^*+={}\\|\\\\&lt;&gt;,\'\"]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="SharedGroupEnabled">false</Property>
        <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
    </UserStoreManager>
```

As you can see, I have modified the UsernameJavaRegEx to allow emails containing "+". However, after restarting the server I still get validation errors:

```
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Username test+@gmail.com is not valid. User name must be a non null string with following format, ^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addUser(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1076)
```

It seems like wso2is is completely ignoring my regex. Email test+@gmail.com should match the given regex.

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Did you have enable Email user name property in carbon.xml file ? If you want to configure new property in user-mgt.xml file as follows,  However, Please try it with and see.

`<Property name="UsernameWithEmailJavaScriptRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9@._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>`